# Function returns argument only after two runs in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am looking to implement this draggable list, everything works fine but my console log show nothing on first try only works second time I run the function, I'll need the `order` variable so I can update the database

```
<SortableListView
    removeClippedSubviews={false}
    style={{ flex: 1 }}
    data={data}
    order={order}
    onRowMoved={(e) => {
    order.splice(e.to, 0, order.splice(e.from, 1)[0])
    this.forceUpdate()
    this.updateList(order)
    }}
    renderRow={(row) => <RowComponent data={row} />}
/>
```

This is my function, I know it's async but not sure what to do about it

```
  updateList = (neworder, e) => {
    console.log('updated')
    console.log('order: ' + order)
    console.log('neworder: ' + neworder)
  }
```

I tried adding a setState and callback inside the `onRowMoved` function like so, same issue

```
this.setState({ neworder: order }, this.updateList)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the:

> componentDidMount()

Inside it call your function.

Or every time your setState is triggered, make the request reload

```
this.setState({ neworder: order}, () => {this.updateList() })
```

Depending on your role, it will be necessary or not to wrap this.updateList in curly braces